# How do I pass parameters in body of the POST request to a Jenkins remotely triggered job?

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins job that can be triggered through a POST API call(i.e. buildWithParameters endpoint).

If I encode the parameters in URL, it works just fine. See an example below:

```
http://localhost:80/job/remote-job-2/buildWithParameters?token=password123&org=example.com
```

However, I would like to pass the parameters in the body of this POST request as shown below:

```
{
"token": "password123"
"org" : "example.com"
}
```

Note: The closest answer I could find is this [What is the format of the JSON for a Jenkins REST buildWithParameters to override the default parameters values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508222/what-is-the-format-of-the-json-for-a-jenkins-rest-buildwithparameters-to-overrid). Unfortunately, this does not work for me when I run this on postman. It fails with a +500 server error.

Comment: You can also do - curl -X POST --data-urlencode "token=${TOKEN}" --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name": "org", "value": "example.com"}]}' http://localhost:80/job/remote-job-2/build

Comment: @Pankaj Thanks for the comments. I need to do this from inside a react app. This is backend API and the parameters must be passed inside the body of a POST request(Not encoded on the URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing by sending a json:

```
'{
  "parameter": [
                 {"name":"token", "value":"password123"}, 
                 {"name":"org", "value":"example.com"}
               ]
}'
```

or

```
'{
   {"name":"token", "value":"password123"},
   {"name":"org", "value":"example.com"}
}'
```

And many other combinations have only worked for me by sending the parameters as standard html form fields.

For example in java/spring/restTemplate:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> jobParams= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
jobParams.add("token", "password123");
jobParams.add("org", "example.com");
return restTemplate.exchange(jarvisUri, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(jobParams, headers), String.class).getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

In python I was driven crazy until I saw that in order to post *form* data I had to pass a dictionary to "data=", not a json string. Here is an example:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/job/Test/job/WithParams/buildWithParameters', auth = ('a_username', 'a_password'), data = { "delay": "0","Weight": "32", "Height": "14"})
```

The "delay": "0" will also build immediately, ignoring any "quiet period" set on the Jenkins job.